# React.js Authentication redirects to login on each refresh

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, react-redux, page-refresh

I noticed that when I refreshed the page on my app, it would blip to the login page then go to the dashboard if I was authenticated. Regardless of what page I refreshed on.

I'm pretty new to react, but I think the problem is in my PrivateRoute.js logic. It goes "else: redirect to login" but doesn't fail on the login page so it follows the "if authenticated redirect to dashboard" route.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  HashRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";

import { Provider as AlertProvider } from "react-alert";
import AlertTemplate from "react-alert-template-basic";

import Header from "./layout/Header";
import Sidebar from "./layout/Sidebar";
import Home from "./common/Home";
import Profile from "./accounts/profile";
import Dashboard from "./leads/Dashboard";
import Alerts from "./layout/Alerts";
import Login from "./accounts/Login";
import Register from "./accounts/Register";
import PrivateRoute from "./common/PrivateRoute";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "../store";
import { loadUser } from "../actions/auth";

// Alert Options
const alertOptions = {
  timeout: 3000,
  position: "top center"
}; 

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(loadUser());
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
          <Router>
            <Fragment>
              <Header />
              <Alerts />
              <div className="container-fluid page-body-wrapper">
                <Sidebar />
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                  <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                  <PrivateRoute exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
                  <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                  <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </Fragment>
          </Router>
        </AlertProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

PrivateRoute.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropType from "prop-types";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, path, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    path={path}
    {...rest}
    render={props => {
      if (auth.isLoading) {
        return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
      } else if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
        return <Component {...props} />;
      } else {
        return <Redirect to="/login" />;
      }
    }}
  />
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { login } from "../../actions/auth";

export class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    username: "",
    password: ""
  };

  static propTypes = {
    login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.login(this.state.username, this.state.password);
  };

  onChange = e => this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

  render() {
    {
      /*if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      return <Redirect to="/dashboard" />;
    }*/
    }
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="col-md-12 m-auto" style={{ maxWidth: 500 }}>
        <div className="card card-body mt-5">
          <h2 className="text-center py-3">Login to Reely.io</h2>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Username</label>
              <input 
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                name="username"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                value={username}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Password</label>
              <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                name="password"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                value={password}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
                Login
              </button>
            </div>
            <p>
              Need an account? <Link to="/register">Register</Link>
            </p>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { login })(Login);
```

auth.js - actions

```
import axios from "axios";
import { returnErrors } from "./messages";

import {
  USER_LOADED,
  USER_LOADING,
  AUTH_ERROR,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAIL,
  LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_FAIL
} from "./types";

// CHECK TOKEN & LOAD USER
export const loadUser = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  // User Loading
  dispatch({ type: USER_LOADING });

  axios
    .get("/api/auth/user", tokenConfig(getState))
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: USER_LOADED,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
      dispatch({
        type: AUTH_ERROR
      });
    });
};

// LOGIN USER
export const login = (username, password) => dispatch => {
  // Headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };

  // Request Body
  const body = JSON.stringify({ username, password });

  axios
    .post("/api/auth/login/", body, config)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_FAIL
      });
    });
};

// REGISTER USER
export const register = ({ username, password, email }) => dispatch => {
  // Headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };

  // Request Body
  const body = JSON.stringify({ username, password, email });

  axios
    .post("/api/auth/register/", body, config)
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_FAIL
      });
    });
};

// LOGOUT USER
export const logout = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .post("/api/auth/logout/", null, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then(res => {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGOUT_SUCCESS
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status));
    });
};

// SETUP CONFIG W/ TOKEN - Helper Function
export const tokenConfig = getState => {
  // Get token from state
  const token = getState().auth.token;

  // Headers
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };

  // If token, add to header config
  if (token) {
    config.headers["Authorization"] = `Token ${token}`;
  }

  return config;
};
```

types.js

```
export const GET_LEADS = "GET_LEADS";
export const DELETE_LEADS = "DELETE_LEADS";
export const ADD_LEAD = "ADD_LEAD";
export const GET_ERRORS = "GET_ERRORS";
export const CREATE_MESSAGE = "CREATE_MESSAGE";
export const USER_LOADING = "USER_LOADING";
export const USER_LOADED = "USER_LOADED";
export const AUTH_ERROR = "AUTH_ERROR";
export const LOGIN_SUCCESS = "LOGIN_SUCCESS";
export const LOGIN_FAIL = "LOGIN_FAIL";
export const LOGOUT_SUCCESS = "LOGOUT_SUCCESS";
export const REGISTER_SUCCESS = "REGISTER_SUCCESS";
export const REGISTER_FAIL = "REGISTER_FAIL";
```

auth.js - reducer

```
import {
  USER_LOADED,
  USER_LOADING,
  AUTH_ERROR,
  LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  LOGIN_FAIL,
  LOGOUT_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_SUCCESS,
  REGISTER_FAIL
} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
  isAuthenticated: null,
  isLoading: false,
  user: null
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true
      };
    case USER_LOADED:
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        isLoading: false,
        user: action.payload
      };
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
    case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
      localStorage.setItem("token", action.payload.token);
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        isLoading: false
      };
    case AUTH_ERROR:
    case LOGIN_FAIL:
    case LOGOUT_SUCCESS:
    case REGISTER_FAIL:
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      return {
        ...state,
        token: null,
        user: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
        isLoading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to put `initialState.isLoading` at `true`?

Comment: Why did that work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes from the `initialState`. You need to set `isLoading` at `true`.

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, path, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    path={path}
    {...rest}
    render={props => {
      if (auth.isLoading) {
        // If initialState.isLoading = false, 
        // then your application will skip this step
        // (just after a refresh)
        return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
      } else if (auth.isAuthenticated) {
        // But because USER_LOADING is not triggered yet,
        // your are not authenticated !
        return <Component {...props} />;
      } else {
        // Then you drop here
        return <Redirect to="/login" />;
      }
    }}
  />
);
```

On my current project, I managed this case with a `initialized` variable (which is false at the beginning):

```js
import React, {FC} from "react"
import {RouteProps, Route, Redirect} from "react-router-dom"

import {useAuthState} from "./context"

const PrivateRoute: FC<RouteProps> = props => {
  const auth = useAuthState()

  if (!auth.initialized) {
    return null
  }

  if (!auth.authenticated) {
    return <Redirect to="/login" />
  }

  return <Route {...props} />
}

export default PrivateRoute
```

Comment: A quite naive solution. Thanks!